# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when posting data to sql table

Tags: c#

I am creating an IT inventory system and need to add all the workstation
information to the Workstation table. i've switched on the debugger and going through the code I receive the error

> "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

The error comes from the line code of `if ((bool)item["Wkst_Status"])`

I have not tried anything as yet as i am new to C#, asp.net as a beginner.

```
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["Emp_Name"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Emp_Surname"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["Department"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["Company"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["Hostname"].ToString();

    if ((bool)item["Wkst_Status"])
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "Active";
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "Inactive";
    }

    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["Make"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["Model"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = tem["ProductNumber"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["Purch_Date"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["WExpiry_Date"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["Memory"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[13].Value = item["Processor"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[14].Value = item["HDD"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[15].Value = item["OS"].ToString();
}
```

after entering the data in the app the data should be written to the sql table

Comment: Well the error is clear, item["Wkst_Status"] is not a bool

Comment: What type is the field "Wkst_Status" in your database? If, for example, it's a char then a cast to bool isn't going to work.

Comment: this error means that item["Wkst_Status"] is not boolean, so it can't be converted to bool directly

Comment: As a PS, you probably should learn about data binding, which will do away with the need for the code to start with.

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can do it in a safer way:

Instead of this:

```
if ((bool)item["Wkst_Status"])
```

Use this:

```
var isActive = Convert.ToBoolean(item["Wkst_Status"]);

if (isActive  == true)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "Active";
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = "Inactive";
    }
```

You can also do null checks, but in your case that won't matter, because probably if the item["Wkst_Status"] is null, you would want the value of the cell to say "InActive"

Comment: Here is a try parse documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Generally TryParse is the safest way to convert in C#. Also have in mind "AS" way, e.g. item as bool which is better than (bool)item, because the latter one will crash and the "AS" way will just give you null.

Answer (score 0):

ty this:

```
if(item["Wkst_Status"] != null)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = (Convert.ToBoolean(item["Wkst_Status"]) ?"Active":"Inactive");
}
```